# tmux mouse mode is being disabled somehow during a session

Tags: terminal, tmux

Sometimes while I'm working, I notice that `tmux` is no longer responding properly to mouse controls (usually as I try to scroll back a pane using the mouse wheel and get iTerm2's own scrolling behaviour instead). What could be causing this? I'm using Karabiner to map Ctrl taps to Esc, so I suspect I'm "accidentally" tapping Ctrl (thereby emitting Esc) and then pressing some key or other that deactivates mouse mode.

I can restore mouse functionality by detaching and reattaching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of issues at play here, so I'll go down the list in order of most-likely to least-likely.

1. `tmux` key binding:

   - I'm not sure there is a default key binding to toggle mouse-mode in tmux, but you can get a list of all of your bindings by executing:
     `<prefix> ?`
   - If you see anything in there related to mouse mode, try disabling the key binding.
2. An issue with Karabiner

   - Remapping `control` to `escape` could potentially cause an issue with the escape codes being sent to the terminal when you move the mouse wheel.
   - Unfortunately I don't know too much about what escape sequences the mouse sends, but Karabiner could very well be the problem.
3. [This iTerm2 issue](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/2464) could be the problem, but I doubt it.

Comment: I found no mouse mode-related keybinding that could disable it. I just tried fiddling around with holding down Esc and doing mouse stuff, and that doesn't seem to do it either. I really don't understand the iTerm2 issue, so I can't tell if it's related.